# Failed to load assembly from stream: System.AggregateException xamarin Build error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-live-player

**I am trying to build application on xamarin live player but it gives me an error**

Failed to load assembly from stream: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/data/data/com.xamarin.live/files/External/.nuget/packages/sqlitepclraw.provider.e_sqlite3.android/1.1.5/lib/MonoAndroid/SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0017d] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at .$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00012] in <5a7d391011b47c3aa745038310397d5a>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/data/data/com.xamarin.live/files/External/.nuget/packages/sqlitepclraw.provider.e_sqlite3.android/1.1.5/lib/MonoAndroid/SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0017d] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00012] in <5a7d391011b47c3aa745038310397d5a>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/data/data/com.xamarin.live/files/External/.nuget/packages/sqlitepclraw.provider.e_sqlite3.android/1.1.5/lib/MonoAndroid/SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0017d] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at .$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00012] in <5a7d391011b47c3aa745038310397d5a>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0

what is the solution for this problem